# Nvidia Gtx 750 ti lagging on linux with nvidia driver

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia

I have a graphic card : **Nvidia Gtx 750 ti** .

Sometimes in **Linux**( tested on : ubuntu , Arch , Fedora and ... ) it lags with `nvidia` driver but with `nouveau`  works fine.

I mean the mouse stops when moving for a few hundredths of a second and moves again ...

There is no problem in **Windows  os**.

When this happens , Removing graphic card from slot and reinstalling helps to solve problem But after a while, the same problem occurs again.

my motherboard is : Gigabyte H310m

Comment: So, the problem is that it only works with the noveau driver, but not with the driver from nvidia directly?

Comment: @CentrixDE yes! this problem happen only on nvidia driver

Comment: @CentrixDE Consider that sometimes this error occurs on nvidia driver not always

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use noveau? If this driver works, I would suggest to just use it, as there probably won't be updates for the official nvidia drivers.

But maybe try an older NVIDIA driver just in case?

Comment: @CentrixDE When I use noveau, many programs do not identify the graphics card, such as the psensor and ...

Comment: Apart from this, I want to solve the problem because the graphics card may be damaged

Comment: If there is no problem on Windows or with noveau it's possible a driver issue instead of an hardware failure. NVIDIA published the last official driver back in 2014 which could definitely cause these problems on modern OS. Did you try to test an older version of your driver?

Comment: no ! i could not find older version of nvidia for archlinux